# Runtime error when aws lambda trying to access dynamoDB - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to access dynamoDB from my Lambda function.
The function has the correct IAM role, and was created using the AWS plugin for Eclipse.
When the code gets to this line:

```
   dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(
                new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()));
```

I get the following runtime exception:

```
   Input: com.xr4p.Request@13a57a3borg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<clinit>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:56)
    at com.xr4p.Dana.handleRequest(Dana.java:30)
    at com.xr4p.Dana.handleRequest(Dana.java:1)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

I have tried to create the function from scratch,the project from scratch and nothing... The same error keeps popping whenever these lines are added.

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Eclipse's project configuration:
Once the "AWS SDK for Java" was added to the "java build path" -> "libraries"  it worked ok.